# Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

```
    Dim tableautemp() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(nomfichier)
    Dim etudianttemp() As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To tableautemp.Length - 1
        etudianttemp() = tableautemp(i).Split(";"c)
        For j As Integer = 0 To 6
            tableau(j, i) = etudianttemp(j)
        Next
    Next
```

I want to read the file and put the lines in a 1d tab, then split each line in another 1d tab then add everything to a 2d tab. But I get "Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array". I don't understand :s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assignment of the array is wrong. This:

```
etudianttemp() = tableautemp(i).Split(";"c)
```

should be:

```
etudianttemp = tableautemp(i).Split(";"c)
```

The error that you got is because it looks like you try to assign to an item in the array rather than the array itself, and then you would need to provide the index of the item. The error message is only based on the fact that the left side of the assignment is wrong, it doesn't take into account the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis in `etudianttemp() = ...` => `etudianttemp = ...` as explained in [Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26832865/2410892) (*don't forget to mark his answer as accepted*)

---

I'll just add that ***you should*** initialize your `tableau` array size *before* attempting to assign values in the loop using `i` and `j`. By the way, if you've deleted some lines in your code to localize your issue, just discard this answer :) .

```
    Dim tableautemp() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(nomfichier)
    Dim etudianttemp() As String
    Dim tailleDimensionJ As Int32 = 6 ' edit accordingly.. Caution: Base 0 => 7 items

    Redim tableau(tailleDimensionJ, tableautemp.length - 1) ' here !

    For i As Integer = 0 To tableautemp.Length - 1
        etudianttemp = tableautemp(i).Split(";"c)
        For j As Integer = 0 To tailleDimensionJ ' and here !
            tableau(j, i) = etudianttemp(j)
        Next
    Next
```

If you don't have a fixed size J dimension, you should set tailleDimensionJ at runtime by parsing each tableautemp(i) first, only keeping the maximum number of items.

```
    Dim tableautemp() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(nomfichier)
    Dim etudianttemp() As String
    Dim tailleDimensionJ As Int32 = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To tableautemp.Length - 1
        etudianttemp = tableautemp(i).Split(";"c)
        If tailleDimensionJ < (etudianttemp.Length - 1)
            tailleDimensionJ = etudianttemp.Length - 1
        End If
    Next

    Redim tableau(tailleDimensionJ, tableautemp.length - 1)

    For i As Integer = 0 To tableautemp.Length - 1
        etudianttemp = tableautemp(i).Split(";"c)
        For j As Integer = 0 To etudianttemp.Length - 1 ' <- change this
            tableau(j, i) = etudianttemp(j)
        Next
    Next
```

[FR] Vous devriez initialiser la taille de votre variable `tableau` *avant* de lui assigner des valeurs dans la boucle for à l'aide de `i` et `j`. Bien entendu, si vous aviez supprimé des lignes de code pour bien cibler le soucis, veuillez ignorer cette remarque :)