# VB.NET - Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub WriteMap()
    Dim CharPos = {1, 1}
    Dim PrintMap As String = ""
    Dim Map(,) As String = {{" ", " ", " "}, {" ", " ", " "}, {" ", " ", " "}}

    While True
        Map(CharPos(0))(CharPos(1)) = "X"

        For y = 0 To Map.GetUpperBound(0)
            For x = 0 To Map.GetUpperBound(1)
                PrintMap += $"{Map(y, x)} "
            Next
            PrintMap += vbLf
        Next
        Console.Write(PrintMap)

        Dim Input = Console.ReadKey()
        Console.Clear()
        PrintMap = ""
    End While
End Sub
```

The error is coming from Map(CharPos(0))(CharPos(1)) = "X"
I have no idea what is causing it as Map.Rank() returns 2
and I have looked around for a solution but so far have only found a way to print the contents of the array but I cant find a way to edit the existing entries in the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832783/number-of-indices-is-less-than-the-number-of-dimensions-of-the-indexed-array)

Comment: @Flimzy The solution to that issue was to remove a set if parenthesis which aren't present in my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared `Map` as a 2D array but you're accessing it like a jagged array.  This:

```
Map(CharPos(0))(CharPos(1)) = "X"
```

should be this:

```
Map(CharPos(0), CharPos(1)) = "X"
```

The way you're doing it, you're treating it as a 1D array of 1D arrays, which a 2D array is not.  To declare `Map` as a jagged array this:

```
Dim Map(,) As String
```

would have to be this:

```
Dim Map()() As String
```